# lag in scroll Recycler View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scroll

I created a program that puts related photos in the Card View, and when the number of items increases and I scroll, the scrolling speed is slow.
And the performance of the program decreases And retrieves images with each scroll. I wanted to see what I can do.?
Thank you.
I used recycler View.

Comment: A good place to start would be to post your RecyclerView adapter along with your thoughts of where you think the problem lies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load and cache image.
- Make sure CardView has a fixed height.
- Avoid heavy work in onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: I did all this, but to no avail